# Bundling react components with tailwind styling using rollup

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, rollupjs

I'm working on a design system that uses tailwind.css.

When running the rollup command, it properly compiles my js and my css, creating two new files inside my `dist` directory: index.js, and index.css.

But for some reason, index.js does not import index.css. I thought I needed to set the `inject` property to true, but it's not working.

Here is my rollup config file:

```
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import terser from "@rollup/plugin-terser";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss";

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

const config = [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        sourcemap: true,
        format: "esm",
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.build.json" }),
      postcss({
        config: {
          path: "./postcss.config.mjs",
        },
        extract: true,
        plugins: [tailwindcss("./tailwind.config.ts"), autoprefixer],
      }),
      peerDepsExternal(),
      commonjs(),

      resolve(),
    ],
  },
];

export default config;
```

I made sure that my index.ts file imports my main scss file.

Did I miss something ?